# iPhone App, WCF REST-based service, ASP.NET_SessionId and .ASPXAUTH

Tags: asp.net, iphone, wcf, sessionid, .aspxauth

I plan to use WCF REST-based web services to communicate with an iPhone app. I'd like to maintain the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie and .ASPXAUTH cookie for the authenticated user across requests. Any suggestion on how you would accomplish this? Would it be a bad idea to send both cookies back and fourth in all requests for the authenticated user?